# Changing date format on php link cakephp

Tags: cakephp, date, format

The following code is the output into a table where I have a list of dates which are also hyperlinks to an event on that date. It currently displays YMD and I would like it to display DMY.

I have tried using 'dateFormat'=>'DMY' in the array but this does not change anything.

> Html->link($shiftsession['Shiftsession']['sessionDate'], array(
>                 'controller' => 'shiftsessions', 
>                 'action' => 'view', 
>                 $shiftsession['Shiftsession']['SessionID']));           ?>

http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/view/203/options-dateFormat

If anyone could shed some light on how you properly use dateFormat I'd be stoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good ole' [PHP date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to the rescue:

```
<?php
//use PHP's date() to format the date in any way you'd like
$theDate = date('DMY', strtotime($shiftsession['Shiftsession']['sessionDate']));

//build the link using the newly formatted date
$this->Html->link($theDate, array(
    'controller' => 'shiftsessions',
    'action' => 'view',
    $shiftsession['Shiftsession']['SessionID']
));
```

(Obviously you could write that whole thing into one line... for example purposes on StackOverflow, it reads better like this imo)

**With CakePHP:**

CakePHP has a nice [Time Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html), but it doesn't have an option to specify exactly what format you'd like.  Instead, it has things like `gmt()`, and `niceShort()`, and `timeAgo()`...etc